# Cordova / Phonegap - can't add android platform - package name is handled incorrectly (dots are replaced with "undefined")

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, path

I'm new to Cordova and I'm trying to add android platform to my app, but it fails:

```
$ cordova create myapp com.example.asd myapp
Creating a new cordova project with name "myapp" and id "com.example.asd" at location "/home/user/Scaricati/android/eclipse/alternativeworkspace/myapp"
$ cd myapp
$ cordova platform add android
Checking Android requirements...
Creating android project...
Preparing android project
{ [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/user/Scaricati/android/eclipse/alternativeworkspace/myapp/platforms/android/src/com/example/asd']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/user/Scaricati/android/eclipse/alternativeworkspace/myapp/platforms/android/src/com/example/asd',
  syscall: 'readdir' }
```

It tries to reach an invalid path.
I tried to investigate the issue and I found out that in src directory package name is handled incorrectly:

```
$ ls platforms/android/src
comundefinedexampleundefinedasd
```

As you can see dots (".") are replaced by "undefined".
By the way simply renaming the directory didn't solve the issue.

Strangely cordova successfully handles package-name in other places:

```
$ grep -ri com.example.asd .
./www/config.xml:<widget id="com.example.asd" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    ./platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:<widget id="com.example.asd" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    ./platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example.asd" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ./platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml:<widget id="com.example.asd" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    ./platforms/android/src/comundefinedexampleundefinedasd/myapp.java:package com.example.asd;
    ./.cordova/config.json:{"id":"com.example.asd","name":"myapp"}
```

My cordova version is

```
$ cordova --v
3.1.0-0.2.0
```

This issue affects "non-cli" Cordova either (I tried to make it work in eclipse).

If you don't know how to fix this issue, but you know where I can see "cordova create" sources, please post it, I would try to develop a quick fix by myself.
Thanks in advance for your help.

## * EDIT *

For those who will find this thread searching for a solution, I'm replying to myself.
I've edited manually sources and I think I removed the bug.

line 128, ~/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.1.0/bin/lib/create.js

```
var package_as_path = package_name.replace(/\./g, path.sep);
```

path.sep is undefined. I just replaced it with path sep of my os ("/")

```
var package_as_path = package_name.replace(/\./g, '/');
```

It seems to work normally now.

Comment: Yikes ... what system are you running, out of curiousity?  Did you have any errors during the installation of cordova that you had to force your way through when using npm?  I'm wondering where this issue comes from... and if it's something that will be fixed any time soon!

Comment: i'm getting the same error, but this solution doesnt work for me..

Comment: If this was in mac, make sure you have full access to the created folder. I do sudo phonegap build android first.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a different solution here: https://github.com/adapt-it/adapt-it-mobile/wiki/Troubleshooting-Development-Work

What you do is, navigate to root project folder via commandline and create the "plugins" folder

```
mkdir plugins
```

Then run the command

```
cordova platform add <platform>
```

The errors should be gone. It seems that cordova somehow can't create the plugins folder.

This was done on Linux-Mint 16 with cordova 3.5.0

Comment: Getting same error and already there is a folder plugins inside

Comment: This worked for me on a Windows 8.1 environment. Thanks!